# How to access and refer variabes and functions in global classes

Tags: android, class, android-activity

I'm creating an app that has five activities. I have one class with functions and variables that are used in all five activities. I have created a local variable in each activity that initializes the class like this;

```
localclass = new globalclass(getResouces());
```

I'm new to android/java development and was wondering about memoryfootprints and such when I tried something. In the first actvity that gets started, localclass get set as formentioned. I then tried to access this variable from the other activities and did this successfully like this in activity second, third and so on;

```
localclass = com.firstactivity.localclass;
```

One of the variables the I use are a reference to application resources. In acticity second on onwards I dont get resources like this;

```
res = getResources();
```

but like this;

```
res = com.firstactivity.localclass.res;
```

This works as long as variables are static. I also access functions in globalclass the same way.

Is this bad pratice?

Comment: First learn about how to write title of question?

Comment: He he he... I tried to find a good title, but didn't fine one that described my question better than the one I gave. Suggestions are welcome!! ;-)

Comment: @user1086500: Your question is good, but the fact why it lacks attention was it doesn't have a good title.

Comment: @user1086500 I don't have any issue about your title but your title is not good and if your question's title is not good then some users are not reading your question.

Comment: It could be something like this- _How to acces/refer local resources in global classes_ or whatever it is. and also dont use signatures(**--TOMMY**), the rectangle displaying your name and repo is actually your signature.

Comment: I understand. I'll try to change it to something more better. But then again, I feel the answers given are good enough to make me reedit my code. Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally using static class as a variable holder really isn't a good practice. Try passing variables you need in other activities by intents instead. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026507/why-are-static-variables-considered-evil) as it explains more why this is not a good approach.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [Application class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html). You create a class that extends Application:

```
public class YourApplication extends Application {
    // functions, variables, whatever it is you need across your whole program
}
```

You get a reference to your application by calling this in your activities/services:

```
YourApplication app = (YourApplication)getApplication();
```

Also, remember to declare the Application in your manifest file.

```
<application android:name="the.package.name.YourApplication" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Based on your and other answers, I'm reediting my code.